# Add DLL in ASP NET Web Service

Tags: asp.net, dll

Today I added DLL in my ASP NET Web Service.I found two ways to add DLL.

**First one is** - Right click on project << Add Reference << Browser << Select the DLL.

**Second one is** - Right click on bin folder << Add Existing Item << Select the DLL.

Both are working fine.So now my question is "**Is there any difference between both ways?**"

If yes then please do reply.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mohit Kumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the 3rd one...

Drag the dll directly into your BIN fodler :)

They all the same, though I suggest the "correct way", add your Libraries through **Add Reference** Menu

Comment: rite Sir..One more I can direct DLL paste in containing folder..;)